# How do ACK packets get matched to SYN numbers?

Tags: tcp

I'm a newbie at networking, learning TCP for fun.

I've been looking at packets on Wireshark, and I was wondering: How do the two sides know that an ACK packet was in response to a specific SYN packet? I know they can go by host and port, which would mostly narrow it down, but do they use any other kind of ID or something for both of them?